# Is there a function (preferably in lubridate) to get the number of weeks in any given year?

Tags: r, lubridate

I can probably hard code a lookup table and reference from that but I am wondering if there is a handy function in any R package that can return the number of weeks in a given year. ISO 8601 calendar is needed.

`lubridate` has the function `isoweek` which returns the week number for a given date

`lubridate::isoweek("2020-12-31")`

`lubridate::isoweek("2021-12-31")`

However, what I need is something like

`isoweeks(2020)` which would return 53

`isoweeks(2021)` which would return 52

Comment: You can wrap those years in a function a la `fun <- function(x) { lubridate::isoweek(sprintf("%d-12-31", x)) }` ? Then `fun(2020:2021)`. Note `fun(2019)` will return `1`

Comment: Thanks. The 1 returned is an issue for me. I would like to have the function general so that it gives me the number of isoweeks in a range of years e.g. 2014:2021 and beyond.

Answer (score 1):

Not aware if there's such a function, but you can create your own function using `lubridate`:

```
weeks <- function(year) {
  
  lubridate::isoweek(paste0(year, "-12-31"))
  
}

weeks(2020)
#53
```

Comment: Thanks. For automation purposes, I would need to have a way of not getting 1 back from particular years.

Comment: This gives me what I want but I am unsure about the stability of this for future years. `weeks <- function(year) {
  
  lubridate::isoweek(paste0(year, "-12-28"))
  
}`

Then `weeks(2014:2021)`